# MySQL query for four tables

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables, let it be A, B, C & D.

Each of these table has one common field, let it be email.

Now I want all the emails which is present in either of B, C or D but NOT in A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f35dc/1

The best way I can think to do this is with 3 separate queries, each left joining to table A.  Using UNION DISTINCT will give you the unique email values from tables B, C, and D that do not exist in table A.  Here's the query I used:

```
SELECT
b.email
FROM
b
LEFT JOIN a ON b.email = a.email
WHERE a.email IS NULL
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT
c.email
FROM
c
LEFT JOIN a ON c.email = a.email
WHERE a.email IS NULL
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT
d.email
FROM
d
LEFT JOIN a ON d.email = a.email
WHERE a.email IS NULL
```

The other answer suggested using a subselect, but my experience with subselects in mySQL is that they are not very performant.

Comment: Thanks Mark, it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `union all` if you want repeated emails or `union` if you don't want repeated emails, and `not in` like this query:

```
select email from B
union select email from C
union select email from D
where email not in (SELECT email FROM A)
```